# Nestjs Mongoose, How to delete array member by its _id?

Tags: mongodb, typescript, mongoose, nestjs

The schema is like this. it's a shopping cart with items:

```
export interface Cart extends mongoose.Document {
  userId: string;
  total: number;
  count: number;
  status: string;
  items: [
    {
      itemId: string;
      itemName: string;
      count: number;
      price: number;
      itemTotal: number;
    },
  ];
}
```

if you look at the mondodb data, there is an _id to each of the members in items array.
I have this _id, and i want to remove an item by that _id.
The problem is, it's typescript, and _id is not part of the schema.
Here is the code i use to delete an item:

```
const cart = await this.cartModel.findOneAndUpdate(
   { _id: dto.cartId },
   { $pull: { items: { _id: '1234567890' } } },
   { new: true },
);
```

Which means, in that specific cart, find the item with _id equals to 1234567890, and delete it.
BUT the _id has red squiggly, as it is not part of my schema.
How can I solve this?

Comment: How does your schema look like? the same as the interface ? or are you using subdocument schemas? If `_id` is not defined in the schema it's an `ObjectId` by default.

Comment: Cast the id to `ObjectId` using `Types.ObjectId(id)`

Answer (score 1):

It shoulds be **id** not **_id**. Because _id is an object. But our query cannot send object to params. So, it should be a hexString.

You can change your entity _id to id by:

```
 @ObjectIdColumn()
 @Transform(id => id.toString())
 id: string;
```

So that, you can use id as hexString anywhere. Hope it helps

Comment: you can always use `Types.ObjectId(objectIdString)` to cast it to `ObjectId` for `mongoose` query

Comment: id is also not valid, as it is not part of my class. I guess it's not mongoose's fault, and in plain javascript it would work well. but the way Nest.js works, i don't have access to that field.

Answer (score 0):

For lack of better solution, i have bypassed this issue by adding a text field called timeStamp. when an item is added to the cart, i push the current time (in ms) to that field, and that is unique enough to distinguish between entries in a shopping cart. In case you wonder, itemId is not good enough, as people can have the same item in 2 or more lines, with different details. I have added of course the new field to my schema, so typescript is not complaining ;)